# Are there mechanics for determining a starting age in D&D BECMI?

Tags: character-creation, dnd-becmi

Is there a mechanical determination for 1st Level character ages in BECMI/Rules Cyclopedia? Appendix 3 character sheets and most 3rd Party sheets suggest that an age should be provided, but I can't find a rules suggestion.

I'm not opposed to creative background, narratives, or other determinate, after all we are grown-ups and quite comfortable with "winging-it,"—I am at least—but given the lean of BECMI, a mechanical method almost seems "expected."

Comment: I've retitled this question with what I am pretty sure is a more fitting title. Please check it still captures the question!

Comment: Moldvay Basic doesn't include age in character creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Age (and height and weight) weren't determined mechanically in any edition until AD&D, and even in AD&D it was only a suggested system rather than the default. Once AD&D introduced the idea, it was (as far as I know) never incorporated into the Basic D&D line.